# Create a "Safari App Extension" for macOS application created with Electron?

Tags: macos, safari, electron, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

Since the release of "Safari App Extension" I have toyed around with creating safari app extensions for native applications using xcode. Now however, I'm attempting to create an extension for an application that was built using the Electron Framework.

I'm wondering if this is possible and if anyone has had any luck accomplishing this goal. I'm unsure how to go about initiating the safari app extension without the use of xcode.

For those unfamiliar with "Safari App Extension" you can add one to an existing native project by opening a MacOS application, going to "File->New->Target->Safari Extension" this will then create the extension within your existing application and make the extension available within Safari->Preferences->Extensions.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You want to run a JS app within a native wrapper within a native extension to a browser

Comment: @MattW. Recently, Apple updated the guidelines so that if you want to create a Safari Extension then you must bundle the extension with a companion Mac Application. I currently have a Mac Application written in Electron and the purpose of this question is to figure out how to bundle the Safari Extension with the application written in Electron.

Comment: @NejKutcharian I'm looking for same thing. Have you got the solution?

Comment: @SkrewEverything Not yet, but if you do find it please post here and I’ll mark it.

Comment: @NejKutcharian Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @marcos1490 unfortunately no

Answer (score -2):

I'm not secure if what I'm saying it's true, but I think that Safari Extensions are writed with Safari apis and/or a language that it isn't javascript (because, on my old Mac, I needed to install an adblocker app with .app extension). The problem is that Electron is based by Chromium and requires javascript and Chromium based extensions. If you want, however, you can [do the inverse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari).
If you are not expert with Chromium extensions, I suggest to you [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/).

P.S.: You can also try to find the same or similar extension that works on Chromium.